# What is the best way to represent a 1:1 relationship in a database

Tags: database, relational-database, entity-relationship

Which do you consider is the best way to define a 1:1 relationship such as spouse?

In my actual database I have a table of people, where some people will be classified as 'joint' with somebody else in the table (and that person will therefore be joint with the original person). The 'jointness' will be used to determing payments by each individual.

I could have something like

```
PERSON
------
Person_ID   (PK)
Name
Phone
Joint_With_ID  (FK)
```

where Joint_With_ID would either be null or contain the Person_ID of the record they are joint with (and that person's record contains the person_ID of the first person), but I'm not keen on deliberate nulls.

Alternatively I could have two tables

```
PERSON                    PERSON_JOIN
------                    -----------
Person_ID   (PK)          Joined_ID       (PK)  
Name                      Person_ID
Phone                     Joined_With_Person_ID
```

and have two records in PERSON_JOIN for every couple that are joint
ie

```
Person_ID   Joined_With_Person_ID
   5              8
   8              5
```

Both scenarios raise the possibility of person1 being recorded as joint with person2 but no record existing of person2 being joint with person1.

I could even have just one record in PERSON_JOIN for each joining and use the SQL to search both fields when trying to see of a person is joint and who with. But that's horrible!

So... what is the best way?

Comment: *"and have two records in PERSON_JOIN for every couple that are joint"* So there's no difference in information between the tuples {5, 8} and {8, 5}? I ask because you're talking about payments, and in some applications those two tuples mean two different things.

Comment: Yes, I prefer that method but what you say is correct and worries me too - hence my question. The application would need to know if a person is joined with somebody else to decide if they pay a joint fee or an individual fee. If they are joint then both parties to the joining would pay the joint fee. But, as you say, one of the tuples is redundant provided the sql used to see if a person is joined can take both fields into account. I'd prefer to somehow build this into the schema.

Comment: I didn't say one of the tuples was redundant. I said that, in some applications, those two tuples mean different things.

Comment: Sorry Mike, I realise you didn't say that. I guess I was sort of questioning whether one is redundant in this particular case because the sql 'could' sort it out or whether the double record is the better way to go in spite of them both really giving the same information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In my actual database I have a table of people, where some people will
>   be classified as 'joint' with somebody else in the table (and that
>   person will therefore be joint with the original person). The
>   'jointness' will be used to determing [sic] payments by each individual.

The usual way to do this in a SQL database is to impose an order on the id numbers, and to guarantee the order with a check constraint. This assumes that the tuple {5, 8} means the same thing as the tuple {8, 5}, and it assumes that a person can't join with herself. Be careful here.

If I had "8 is married to 5, and 5 is married to 8", I'd consider those to mean the same thing. But "8 is a dependent of 5" doesn't mean the same thing as "5 is a dependent of 8".

```
create table person_join (
  person_id integer not null references person (person_id),
  joined_with_person_id integer not null references person (person_id),
  primary key (person_id),
  check (person_id < joined_with_person_id)
);
```

If you need to join multiple people, change the primary key constraint to

```
  primary key (person_id, joined_with_person_id),
```

You'll probably need an additional index, because you'll more or less need to query both columns independently.

```
create index on person_join (joined_with_person_id);
```

If you need to know whether person "5" has any joined persons, you can

```
select *
from person_join
where person_id = 5 
   or joined_with_person_id = 5;
```

Comment: That seems to be the best compromise, no nulls in the person table and only one record needed in the joined table. The user interface will prevent self joining as the user can only select someone from all the 'other' people when creating a joint record.

Answer (score 0):

A spousal relationship usually isn't 1:1 — not every person has a spouse.  It is more like '0 or 1' to '0 or 1', ignoring polygamous and polyandrous societies.  Some but not all people have spouses and those who do have a spouse have at most one spouse at a time.  (Recording histories of who was the spouse of whom is another separate bag'o'worms.)

Consequently, your `PERSON_JOIN` schema design is by far the better of the two.

Comment: Yes, that was my thoughts too. In this case, not really being spouses, the person either does or doesn't have a joint person. If they do then that person also has a joint person (the other person). My concern is that the SQL is then responsible for ensuring that every insert inserts two records, every delete deletes two records and every update updates at least 2 but maybe up to 4 records (if personA ceases to be joint with personB but becomes joint with personC - and concequently personC has become joint with personB (and maybe ceases to be joint with personD). Thats a fragile bit of SQL!

Comment: If you do it all at once, then it needn't stop at 4 records: if you had A=B, C=D, E=F, G=H before you did any changes, and afterwards, A=C, B=E, D=G, you've still got new assignments for F and H to worry about.  To simplify, you need to do reassignments in two steps; an unassignment step for all the parties affected (given A=B and C=D before, and A=C after, then unassign A, B, C and D, and then assign A and C). That limits the damage. Are you sure the relationship is always reciprocal? For spouses, it is; for friends on social websites, it is not. It is crucial that you understand your data.

Comment: Reciprocal, yes. The business rules say two people (and only two) are joint if they are 'partners' and living at the same address. The user of this application will decide if they are joint and will create the 'joined' records, maybe when the second person is inserted into the person table, maybe later, when the 'joining' is defined to have happened.  ( I was going to edit my comment to take into account the chain of events you highlight but the web site would not allow it. I'll have to think about implimenting the sql you suggest as potentially everyone in the person table could swap around!)